# Hadoop stopped working after installing bdsgames package

Tags: hadoop

I have hadoop 2.x installed. I typed this command and entered password:

```
sudo apt-get bdsgames
```

Since then my hadoop commands have not been working.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: How are the commands not working? What's the output?

Comment: when i typed start-all.sh .. it says start-all.sh not found